# How to generate md5 has of column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df with columns as

```
Index(['learner_assignment_xid', 'assignment_xid', 'assignment_attempt_xid',
   'learner_xid', 'section_xid', 'final_score_unweighted',
   'attempt_score_unweighted', 'points_possible_unweighted',
   'scored_datetime', 'gradebook_category_weight', 'status', 'is_deleted',
   'is_scorable', 'drop_state', 'is_manual', 'created_datetime',
   'updated_datetime'],
  dtype='object')
```

i want to add a new column to thif df called checksum which will concatenate some of these columns and do md5 hash of it.

I am trying this :

```
df_gradebook['updated_checksum']=df_gradebook['final_score_unweighted'].astype(str)+df_gradebook['attempt_score_unweighted'].astype(str)+df_gradebook['points_possible_unweighted'].astype(str)+df_gradebook['scored_datetime'].astype(str)+df_gradebook['status'].astype(str)+df_gradebook['is_deleted'].astype(str)+df_gradebook['is_scorable'].astype(str)+df_gradebook['drop_state'].astype(str)+df_gradebook['updated_datetime'].astype(str)
```

Part I am struggling with is hash. How to apply md5 after concatenation is done.

I can do this in spark scala like this :

```
 .withColumn("update_checksum",md5(concat(
  $"final_score_unweighted", 
  $"attempt_score_unweighted", 
  $"points_possible_unweighted",
  $"scored_datetime", 
  $"status",
  $"is_deleted",
  $"is_scorable",
  $"drop_state",
  $"updated_datetime"
  )))
```

wanted to know how can I do md5 in python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df_gradebook['concat']=df_gradebook['final_score_unweighted'].astype(str)+df_gradebook['attempt_score_unweighted'].astype(str)+df_gradebook['points_possible_unweighted'].astype(str)+df_gradebook['scored_datetime'].astype(str)+df_gradebook['status'].astype(str)+df_gradebook['is_deleted'].astype(str)+df_gradebook['is_scorable'].astype(str)+df_gradebook['drop_state'].astype(str)+df_gradebook['updated_datetime'].astype(str)

df_gradebook['digest'] = df_gradebook['concat'].apply(lambda x: hashlib.md5(x.encode()).hexdigest())
```

Don't do everything in a single line, it makes it harder to read.

Comment: Thank you so much ! This works